# Entity Framework 6.4 Duplicating database name on tables ex: DatabaseName.DatabaseName.TableName

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework is duplicating database name on tables ex: `DatabaseName.DatabaseName.TableName`. My connection string config and `web.config` do not have duplication in them. Has anyone seen this before?

As you see from the error the table is:

> MySqlException: Table 'nsf_erc_db.nsf_erc_db.personnel' doesn't exist

When it should be table `nsf_erc_db.personnel`

[image]

Comment: Are you using EntityTypeConfiguration classes? If so, check for `ToTable` declarations and ensure that they aren't accidentally listing the database name as the schema. I.e. should be `ToTable("personnel");` not `ToTable("personnel", "nsf_erc_db");` This applies to `[Table()]` attributes as well on the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I've had issues with Entity Framework, I'll sometimes delete and re-add everything to the model. Goes without saying, but just to be safe, make sure you got a version of your project you can role back to.

To do this, select all of your tables in your model -> right click any of the tables -> select `Delete from model`.

Once everything is gone, right click in the empty model space and select `Update model from database...` and then re-add all your tables from the `Add` tab.

If doing that still doesn't work, you might have to manually go into the `.edmx` file and do some changes yourself. Messing around in the `Model Browser` could work too.